# what does &fun() refer to in the program?

Tags: c++

This is an example problem to demonstrate the use of references in c++. i'm a beginner and this is my first time learning about references. i don't understand why we use `&fun()`. what does it mean?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

    int &fun(){
        static int x = 10;
        return x;
    }
    
    int main(){
        int &y=fun();
        y = 20;
        cout<<fun();
    }
```

output : 20

Comment: `fun` is a function which returns an `int &` (ref to `int`). You return a reference to a static variable `x`, and this is assigned to `y`. `y = 20` changes `x`, and this can be seen when you `cout<<fun()`.

Comment: `int &` instead of `int` means that the function returns a reference to `int` instead of a plain `int`.

Comment: Whitespace doesn't really matter to the parser. `int &fun()`, `int& fun()`, `int   &   fun()`, they all mean the same thing - a function `fun()` that returns an `int&` reference.

Comment: Related: [quoting out of context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoting_out_of_context). Same issue applies to your question. If you quote only part of an English sentence, you risk leaving out key words that affect the meaning. If you focus on only part of a line of (well-formatted) C++ code, you risk leaving out symbols that affect the meaning. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent syntax is `int& fun()`.
So this function returns a *reference* to 'x' (that is static), so later in main you can modify it (`y = 20` does change the `x` inside the function).
So another invocation returns 20, as the `x` had been changed.

Comment: what happens if i don't use `&` in `int &fun()` ?

Answer (score 1):

`int &` means `fun()` is returning a reference to an `int`. In `main()`, that reference is assigned to `y`, and the value of `y` is modified to 20, also changing the value of `x` to 20.